# how to use knockout.js to add one item or delete an item by clicking

Tags: javascript, user-interface, knockout.js, data-binding

I want to add an Item by clicking "Add one Item" and remove an Item by clicking "Remove One Item"
I don't know where should I use data-bind and how can I add to the People array in my code. please help me.

this is my code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: people, as: 'person'}">
<!-- ko foreach: person -->
<div class="item form-collection-group " >
    <div class="title active">
        <span class="accordion-title" data-bind="text : fullName"> title </span>
    </div>
    <div class="content form-collection-content-holder active">               

                    <label class=""> first name </label>
                    <div class="ui input">
                        <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: lastName" >
                    </div>
                    <label class=""> lastName </label>
                    <div class="ui  input">
                        <input  data-bind="textInput: firstName" type="text"  >
                    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
<br>
<button>add one field</button>
<button>remove one field</button>

 <script>
 var ViewModel = function() {
 var self = this;
 self.firstName = ko.observable('');
 self.lastName = ko.observable('');
 self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return self["firstName"].call() + " " + self.lastName() + " Title ";
   }, self);
 };

 ko.applyBindings({
    people: [
                     [new ViewModel()] ,[new ViewModel()] 
             ]
 });

 </script>
```

Comment: this is link of my cod :
https://jsfiddle.net/pzso5897/28/

Answer (score 1):

so typically when adding and deleting items you are going to want to use and observable array. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html.  your add button click binding will push a new item to the array. then the delete button will call the parent remove from array.   here is a working fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/33457/  or you can run the snippet below

```js
function person(firstName, lastName) {
  var self = this;
  this.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
  this.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
  this.fullName = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
  }, this);
 

}

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.firstName = ko.observable('');
  this.lastName = ko.observable('');
  this.people = ko.observableArray();
  this.add = function() {
    self.people.push(new person(self.firstName(), self.lastName()));
  }
  this.remove = function(row) {
    self.people.remove(row);
  }
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: people">
  Title:
  <span class="accordion-title" data-bind="text : fullName"> </span>
  <button data-bind="click: $parent.remove">X</button>
</div>
<div>
  <input data-bind="textInput: firstName" placeholder="first name" />
  <input data-bind="textInput: lastName" placeholder="last name" />
  <button data-bind="click: add">add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Bryan but it's not what I want to do. according to my example, firsName and lastName are bound to own title. I don't want to change this part. when click to add button user should see another row with two input (firstName and lastName) and one span (title). pay attention that binding should be work yet. I hope I can explain it good for you